# Painting phylogenetic trees with phytools by edge.length

Tags: r, phylogeny, ape-phylo

I need to paint manually some phylogenetic trees into two regimes, "0" and "1". I found out that it is possible to do that with the functions `paintSubTree()` and `paintBranches()` from the `phytools` package. The problem is that by using these functions, one can paint the trees only by specific branches or nodes:

```
library(ape)
library(phytools)

tree <- rtree(4)
tree <- paintBranches(tree = tree, edge = 4, state = "1", anc.state="0")
plotSimmap(tree,lwd=4)
```

[image: Tree generated with the code above]

I need to paint the tree according to the **edge.length**, e.g., at time 0.7 (so that only the middle of branch *t4* would be red).
Is there a function that could be used for that purpose?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you really need. Do you want a specific point on the branch to be red (e.g. at time 0.7) or a section of the branch to be red (e.g. between time time 0.7 and t4)?

Comment: A section, sorry for not being clearer!

Comment: One way would be to add internal nodes on along the branches so that the ancestor from `t1` and `t4` connects to an internal node `n1` at time 0.7 that then in turns connects to `t4`. You can then colour the branch (`n1`,`t4`).

Comment: Thanks! I'm pretty new to phytools/ape; could you tell me how this could be achieved? Is there a specific function for doing this?